# python colorbar can set only one value to be a specific value?

Tags: python, background, colorbar, colormap

My image has a donut shape and I only want to have different colors on that donut shape. Other than that want to make it black. How to set only the background to be black?

```
    fig, axe = plt.subplots()
    im2 = axe.imshow(data1, vmin=-30, vmax=5, cmap='viridis')
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([1, 0.15, 0.04, 0.7])
    fig.colorbar(im2, cax=cbar_ax)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the color map and setting the value for 0 yourself:

```py
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap("viridis").copy()
cmap.set_under(color='black')    
im2 = axe.imshow(data1, vmin=0.0000001, vmax=5, cmap=cmap)
```

Comment: This makes all values <0 black. Or is there any way that I can multiply resulted image and masked image?